# Global Parameter Lists for Azure Devops Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm looking for a way to reference a global list of values in Azure Devops Pipelines.   Similar to how Jenkins has Global Choice Parameter.

I want to be able to update one list, and have that reflected in every pipeline that references that parameter.  I don't want to be updating dozens of pipelines to add a value to a list.  It would be nice if that would be easily available to other projects too

Looked through the list of parameter types and I'm not seeing the concept of global list parameters.

Answer (score 0):

That capability doesn't exist. A top-level pipeline defines its parameters, and those parameters are what are exposed to users at queue-time. There's no ability to source those parameters from a separate source.